# How transfer data from middleware to view

Tags: python, django

Got a little problem. In my middleware class i have function.

```
    def process_view(self, request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs):

        r = 'test'

       return None
```

How i can return `r` to View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) , `callback_kwargs` will be passed to the view.

```
callback_kwargs['r'] = 'test'
```

Now view will receive this is in kwargs.

Comment: ty for the your time